# Wi-Fi connection cannot be established once suspended (sleep). Need to restart system - ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, 15.04

Connection to wifi cannot be established once the system wakes up from suspended mode or connection gets disconnected. Only restarting the system makes it work.